# Two Dell st2210 Monitors, one is brighter than the other!

Tags: multiple-monitors

I just got a dual monitor setup that consists of two Dell ST2210 brand new monitors, conneted to Windows 7 Box with nVidia GeForce GT 220. The monitors are connected via VGA and HDMI ports, one monitor is noticeably brighter than the other. Is there by any chance any possible S/W configuration problem that might lead to this problem ? I just want to know before calling the Dell Support!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* that the a brightness control in the nVidia control panel may be set incorrectly, however it's fairly unlikely. It is also possible that if you're using one HDMI and one VGA connection, brightness may be being controlled digitally for one monitor and controlled via the hardware controls on the other monitor. I would check those controls first.

Comment: I already did. I guess I will end up calling the customer care (which is not something i like!)

Comment: Alright - so it turned out that whichever monitor I connect through HDMI it becomes brighter. Any thoughts?